# Java Spring Data JPA with annotation not working with where

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to do this sql query:

> SELECT auth_name FROM person WHERE auth_name = "myemail@gmail.com" AND
>   state=1;

but in the orm of springboot. Can you help me?

This is what I got so far.

**Person repository:**

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p where auth_name = :username AND state= :state")
public List<Person> findAllActiveUsers(@Param("username") String username,@Param("state") byte state);
```

**Controller**

```
 System.out.println(personRepository.findAllActiveUsers(usuario.getAuthName(), (byte) 1));
```

**Error:**

> "exception": "java.lang.StackOverflowError"

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: How can anyone help when you post none of the stack trace, or the LOG of the JPA provider? And FYI Spring has no "ORM", it just uses a JPA provider.

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm assuming you have an infinite loop somewhere. Can't help you find that until you post more information eg. stacktrace, service code etc. BUTTT, in the meantime, Spring has the ability to derive the query from the method name directly, so you could simplify your query to be

```
public List<Person> findAllByUsernameAndState(String username, String state);
```